Which movie or television series contains this character?
I saw a drawing of a familiar character, however, I don't remember which movie or series she was from. The drawing was of a girl with white torn clothes holding a handheld telescope, a machete-like sword strapped around her waist and a green lizard on her shoulder. The background was a beach with trees.
I'm certain this is a children's (or family) movie or series from at least 10 (probably ~15) 7 years ago1. I'm also certain that she is the (or a) main character.
The drawing is not a direct picture (screenshot) so I couldn't use an image search. I did try to Google with this description, but found nothing of help. I'm aware that it's not a lot of details, but I'm thinking that it's unique enough to be identified.
1 Corrected after I saw the answer.

Do you have a digital copy of the image? No amount of description can replace an actual image.

@Catija No, otherwise I would have posted it. It's on the wall of a movie theater and they don't like people taking pictures there. Honestly, I thought a Google search would net me the result pretty fast considering the unique combination.

That would be Nim's Island. The movie was based on a children's/young adult book of the same name and starred Abigail Breslin in the eponymous role, with Gerard Butler playing her biologist father, and Jodie Foster playing her hero/author.  
The movie itself had three main parts. The father goes on a trip to view/study bio-luminescence (either the plankton was named for the daughter, or the daughter for the plankton, I don't recall which was true), leaving Nim alone on her island.  
Then there is the story of Nim on the island. Her island is "invaded" by tourists and she is also frightened by a storm. She calls for help from an author who is a world traveler/adventuress extraordinaire.  
Lastly there is the story of the author, played by Foster. IIRC, she is a famous author of a series of adventure traveler books while in real life she has terrible acrophobia, unable to even leave her apartment. She faces her fears and goes on her first real adventure, finally making it to the island to help Nim.  
It was a very well done (and terribly underrated) movie.  
Here is a the image (from the movie's poster) to which I believe you are referring:

Here's a close up of the girl and her telescope and lizard companion (in the movie, it was Abigail Breslin):


Nailed it! Knew it can't be that hard to identify what with the "telescope - lizard - machete" combination. Though it seems I was very wrong about the year.
